# PyQt using classes to show button

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, qwidget

Getting very stuck here, I am trying to learn how to use classes, and so simply want to show a button on a window when the button is in a different class. Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 600)
        main_menu = Menu()

        self.show()

class Menu(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Quit")
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.move(100,100) 
        btn.show()
        print("Hello I am a menu")




def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = Window()

    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This works so far as I get a window, but no button on it, howerver the print message I put in works. What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: don't mess with buttons in other classes.

Comment: change to `sys.exit(app.exec_())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialize the parent class in `Menu`, in addition to passing the parent to that class and the button.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 600)
        main_menu = Menu(self)
        self.show()

class Menu(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Quit", self)
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.move(100,100) 
        print("Hello I am a menu")

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = Window()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: `sys.exit(app.exec_())` instead

Comment: eyllanesc, no problem.

Comment: Thank you very much eyllanesc, that gives me a good starting point.

Comment: @iFunction 
If my answer helps you, mark it as correct please

Comment: @furas, I completely see your point, that looks messy, actually, I am trying to properly understand classes, for what I want, I want to use a class to define the menu for my application